first order expansion of Hadamard product in a degenerate limit
How would I calculate something like this
$$
\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T}{\left(\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T\right)\cdot\vec{\mathbf{1}}}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T}{\left(\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T\right)\cdot\vec{\mathbf{1}}}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{x}+\epsilon \ d\vec{x}\right)\right)\odot\left(\left(\frac{\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T}{\left(\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T\right)\cdot\vec{\mathbf{1}}}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{x}'+\epsilon \ d\vec{x}'\right)\right)+O(\epsilon^2)
$$
where

$\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix
$\vec{\mathbf{1}}$ is the column vector that is all $1$s
division is taken component-wise
$\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product (i.e. component-wise multiplication)
$^{-1}$ is the matrix inverse
$\cdot$ denotes the regular dot- or matrix product
A common subexpression is $\sum_i{a_i} = \vec{\mathbf{1}}\cdot\vec{a} = \alpha$ which is a consequence of the normalization.

Note, that the matrix $A=\frac{\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}(\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T)}{\left(\mathbb{I}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\vec{a}^T\right)\cdot\vec{\mathbf{1}}}$ degenerates into constant rows $\frac{1}{\alpha}\vec{a}^T$ as $\epsilon\to0$ and so the inverse there only makes sense as a limiting process.
Furthermore, the division makes sure, that the vector $\vec{\mathbf{1}}$ stays fixed by the transform.
The full object describes a situation where you bring all vectors $\vec{x} \in \mathbf{U}$ into a vector space $A \vec{x} \in \mathbf{V}$ where things are skewed towards the axis defined by $\vec{\mathbf{1}}$ in a weighted fashion as determined by $\vec{a}$, take the Hadamard product between two such vectors $(A\vec{x})\odot(A\vec{x}')$, and then go back again. In the limit $\epsilon\to0$, this skewing goes all the way to full collapse onto a single line.
I have painstakingly tried doing this for a small number of components and seen what happens there: Clearly some sort of product rule type deal holds for this. If these were simple functions in $\mathbb{R}$, it'd look like
$$
f^{-1}\left(f(x + \epsilon \ dx) f(x' + \epsilon \ dx')\right) = f^{-1}\left(f(x) f(x')\right) + \frac{dx f(x')\frac{df}{d\text{x}}(x) + dx' f(x) \frac{df}{d\text{x}}(x')}{\frac{df}{d\text{x}}\left(f^{-1}\left(f(x) f(x')\right)\right)}+O(\epsilon^2)
$$
Indeed I seem to be getting something of the form
$$
A_i^{j k} x_j x'_k + \epsilon \left(A_i^{j k} dx_j x'_k + A_i^{j k} x_j dx'_k + {dA}_i^{j k} x_j x'_k \right) + O(\epsilon^2)
$$
where $A_i^{j k}$ and $dA_i^{j k}$ only involve the components $a_i$ of $\vec{a}$.
While for small dimensions, I can do this more or less component-by-component by hand, I'd like a general form (the above is, of course, merely a template), and moreover, if possible, rather than involving tensors like $A_i^{j k}$, I'd prefer that form to be expressed as much as possible in terms of dot products $\cdot$ and Hadamard products $\odot$ of the vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{x}', d\vec{x}, d\vec{x}', \vec{a}, \ \text{and} \ \vec{\mathbf{1}}$, as well as $\alpha$, to make it as clear as possible how it relates to the original form.
Here is the calculation for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (hopefully without typos):
$$A\left[\epsilon\right] =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a+\epsilon }{a+b+\epsilon } & \frac{b}{a+b} \\
 \frac{a}{a+b} & \frac{b+\epsilon }{a+b+\epsilon } \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a+\epsilon }{\alpha +\epsilon } & \frac{b}{\alpha } \\
 \frac{a}{\alpha } & \frac{b+\epsilon }{\alpha +\epsilon } \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$A^{-1}[\epsilon]=\frac{1}{\det\left(A[\epsilon]\right)}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{b+\epsilon }{a+b+\epsilon } & -\frac{b}{a+b} \\
 -\frac{a}{a+b} & \frac{a+\epsilon }{a+b+\epsilon } \\
\end{array}
\right) = \frac{1}{\det\left(A[\epsilon]\right)} \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{b+\epsilon }{\alpha +\epsilon } & -\frac{b}{\alpha } \\
 -\frac{a}{\alpha } & \frac{a+\epsilon }{\alpha +\epsilon } \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
A_i^{jk} = \frac{1}{\alpha \left(\alpha^2-2 a b\right)}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a^3+2 a b^2 \\
 b^3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b^3 \\
 -a b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -a^2 b \\
 a^3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a^3 \\
 2 a^2 b+b^3 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
dA_i^{jk} = \frac{1}{\left(\alpha \left(\alpha^2-2ab\right)\right)^2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 b \left(\alpha^4+3 a^2 b^2-4 a b \alpha^2\right) \\
 a^3 b^2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a^3 b^2 \\
 -a^4 b \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -a b^4 \\
 a^2 b^3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a^2 b^3 \\
 a \left(\alpha^4+3 a^2 b^2-4 a b \alpha^2\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Your very first term is a matrix divided by a vector. How exactly does that work?  I assume that you actually meant to multiply the vector in the denominator by ${\tt1}^T;$

I wrote that division is taken to be component-wise - in this case, each column gets divided by each of the component's column. The goal is to arrive at a matrix that takes (1 1 1) to (1 1 1)

$\def\frae{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}$
$\def\fraae{\frac{\alpha}{\epsilon}}$
$\def\I{\mathbf{I}}$
$\def\a{\mathbf{a}}$
$\def\one{\mathbf{1}}$
$\def\qty#1{\left( #1 \right)}$
$\def\bp{\mathbf{x}_\epsilon}$
$\def\bq{\mathbf{y}_\epsilon}$
$\def\fraxp{{\a^\intercal \bp}}$
$\def\fraxq{{\a^\intercal \bq}}$
$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$
This answer does not provide any major simplification but it is too long to be a comment.
First note that
$$
\qty{\I + \frae \one \a^\intercal} \one
=
\one + \frae \one \alpha
=\qty{1+\fraae}\one
$$
therefore
$$
\frac{\I + \frae \one \a^\intercal}{\qty{\I + \frae \one \a^\intercal} \one}
=\frac{\epsilon \I + \one \a^\intercal}{\alpha+\epsilon}.
$$
Using the Sherman-Morrison formula
$$
\qty{\frac{\epsilon \I + \one \a^\intercal}{\alpha+\epsilon}}^{-1}
=\frac{{\alpha+\epsilon}}{\epsilon}\I - \frae \one \a^\intercal.
$$
Replace ${\bf x}'$ with $\bf y$ and denote ${\bf x} + \epsilon d{\bf x}$ as $\bp$ and ${\bf y} + \epsilon d{\bf y}$ as $\bq$. Then we can modify the original expression to
$$
\frac{\epsilon \bp \odot \bq + \qty{\a^\intercal \bp}\bq + \qty{\a^\intercal \bq}\bp}{\alpha+\epsilon}
-
\frac{\epsilon \a^\intercal \qty{\bp \odot \bq}+\qty{\a^\intercal \bp}\qty{\a^\intercal \bq}}{\qty{\alpha+\epsilon}^2}\one.
$$

Do you wanna flesh this out into a full answer so I can accept this? This was the key I needed to solve this. The main complication was the inverse matrix that you dealt with: The result ought to be $\frac{1}{\alpha}(a^Ty\ x+a^Tx\ y)-\frac{1}{\alpha^2}a^Tx\ a^Ty\ \mathbf{1}+\epsilon(\frac{1}{\alpha}(x\odot y+a^Tdy\ x+a^Tdx\ y+a^Ty\ dx+a^Tx\ dy)-\frac{1}{\alpha^2}(a^Ty\ x+a^Tx\ y+(a^T\ x\odot y+a^Tdy\ a^Tx+a^Tdx\ a^Ty)\mathbf{1}+\frac{2}{\alpha^3}(a^Tx\ a^Ty)\mathbf{1})$

The solution could be made more compact by substituting $
\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(X'\vec{x}+X\vec{x}'\right)-\frac{XX'}{\alpha^2} \vec{\mathbf{1}}+\epsilon\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\vec{x}\odot+dX'\vec{x}+dX\vec{x}'+X'd\vec{x}+Xd\vec{x}'\right)-\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\left(X'\vec{x}+X\vec{x}'+\left(X\odot+dX'X+dXX'\right)\vec{\mathbf{1}}\right)+\frac{2XX'}{\alpha^3}\vec{\mathbf{1}}\right)
$ where $\alpha = \vec{a}^T\vec{\mathbf{1}}$, $\vec{x}\odot=\vec{x}\odot\vec{x}'$, $\vec{a}^T\vec{x}=X$ and $\vec{a}^Td\vec{x}=dX$ and likewise for $x'$ and $x\odot$.

No need to accept the answer, glad I was able to help you. I notice you have $\frac{1}{\alpha}$, $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$, $\frac{1}{\alpha^3}$ factors. Are you using $\alpha+\epsilon \approx \alpha$?

Not quite sure what you mean. For the $O(1)$ term, this is basically just the limit where $\epsilon\to 0$ so the $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ term there just comes from the expression you already showed. For the $O(\epsilon)$ order terms, they basically amount to derivatives by $\vec{x}, \vec{x}', X, X' \text{and} \ \alpha$ just like how $f(t+\epsilon dt) = f(t) + \epsilon f'(t) dt + O(\epsilon^2)$ or $f^{-1}(f(x+\text{d}x\epsilon)f(y+\text{d}y\epsilon))=f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))+\frac{\left(\text{d}xf(y)f'(x)+\text{d}yf(x)f'(y)\right)}{f'\left(f^{-1}(f(x)f(y))\right)}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon
^2\right)$

For a function like $\frac{1}{\left(\alpha+\epsilon\right)^n}$ we have $\frac{1}{\left(\alpha+\epsilon\right)^n} = \frac{1}{\alpha^n}-\frac{n}{\alpha^{1+n}}\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon^2\right)$ and for something like $\frac{\epsilon}{\left(\alpha+\epsilon\right)^n}$ we get $\frac{\epsilon}{\left(\alpha+\epsilon\right)^n}=\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha^{n}}+O\left(\epsilon^2\right)$
